# 500 - No valid database connection:MySQL server has gone away

Tags: joomla, internal-server-error

I have a website under the joomla in one of the hosting servers. It was working fine until yesterday. But starting from yesterday when I open the web site it gives me following error:

```
500 - No valid database connection:MySQL server has gone away SQL=SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(a.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", a.id, a.alias) ELSE a.id END as slug, CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(cc.alias) THEN CONCAT_WS(":", cc.id, cc.alias) ELSE cc.id END as catslug FROM jos_content AS a INNER JOIN jos_categories AS cc ON cc.id = a.catid INNER JOIN jos_sections AS s ON s.id = a.sectionid WHERE a.state = 1 AND ( a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2012-03-04 17:59:41' ) AND ( a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2012-03-04 17:59:41' ) AND s.id > 0 AND a.access <= 0 AND cc.access <= 0 AND s.access <= 0 AND s.published = 1 AND cc.published = 1 ORDER BY a.created DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Or sometimes it just says :

```
Internal Server Error.

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What could be wrong with it? Or it is the host center who has a problem?

Comment: It means ... the database connection has gone away; you no longer have a connection. The socket is an ex-socket. The only reason it was there at all was that its feet were nailed to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Change the database type from mysql to mysqli.